# opencv error: Couldn't load opencv_contrib: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, javacv

I am experiencing with Face Recognition and hence followed all the steps for the opencv static initialization [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization). Also i've copied all the .so files from the opencv to my libs folder. But when i try to call
**com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(2,8,8,8,200);**  , it gives error saying that "*Couldn't load opencv_contrib: findLibrary returned null*". please help me out.